# how to show some data at the time of report download

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have to make headers in my reports what i want when some one see the report in report viewer it should not show the headers of the report but when i export the report header should be present in to the report.
Is it possible to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SSRS 2008R2, you can use **Globals!RenderFormat.Name** method to achieve your required output. But using this method, you can hide all the header controls but there will be blank space appeared for the report header in report preview.

Take a look into

[Use of RenderFormat method in R2](http://www.bi-rootdata.com/2012/10/efficient-way-of-handling-excel.html)

Comment: Thanks Aftab this is working.still is there not any way so that i can remove the blank-space in report preview.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no workaround to remove blank space in preview.